# Hiding level in viewer Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

After I upload `file.rvt` into bucket and call API it to web app. Is there anyway to code for hiding level in viewer?

[image]

Comment: You could search for all Categories that matches the displayName of Level and from there use viewer.hide(ids) of those elements. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to collect all elements from your model:

```
const instanceTree = model.getData().instanceTree;
const rootId = instanceTree.getRootId();

function getAllDbIds(rootId, instanceTree) {
var alldbId = [];
if (!rootId) {
    return alldbId;
}
var queue = [];
queue.push(rootId);
while (queue.length > 0) {
    var node = queue.shift();
    alldbId.push(node);
    instanceTree.enumNodeChildren(
        node,
        function (childrenIds) {
            queue.push(childrenIds);
        }
    );
}

return alldbId;
};
```

Second - get all elements with the name "Level"

`const levelId = allIds.filter((x) => instanceTree.getNodeName(x).includes("Level"))`

Third step - remove elements by Id in the viewer:

`viewer.impl.visibilityManager.setNodeOff(levelId, true)`